# Load and save a list

Tags: c#, xml, list

I have a list as defined below that is populated from a `GridView`. Everything is OK.

What is the best method of saving / loading this list to/from a file (XML or otherwise is OK)?

Note: In the future, I will be encrypting the file.

**C# Code**

```
List<Item> lstNewItems = new List<Item>(); // Control Items  
lstNewItems.Clear();

foreach (GridViewRow PendingItemUnderControl in GridViewPendingList.Rows)
{
    Item NewItem = new Item();
    NewItem.Paramater = PendingItemUnderControl.Cells[0].Text.ToLower();
    NewItem.Type = (String)Session["BrowseType"];
    lstNewItems.Add(NewItem);
}

public class Item
{
    public Item(string Paramater, string Type)
    {         
        _Paramater = Paramater;
        _Type = Type;
    }
    private string _Paramater;
    [DataMember]
    public string Paramater
    {
        get { return _Paramater; }
        set { _Paramater = value; }
    }
    private string _Type;
    [DataMember]
    public string Type
    {
        get { return _Type; }
        set { _Type = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe easiets way is using XmlSerializer to do it for you but please share Item class definition to be sure you can use it without any changes

Comment: The easiet way is to use Binary serialization (BinaryFormatter).

Comment: @sll i jave added the item definition to my question. is XMLSerializer still the correct answer?

Comment: got it using XmlSerializer thanks

Comment: Yes, for such a simple classes XmlSerializer is the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution C# Code**

```
#region Save the object

            // Create a new XmlSerializer instance with the type of the test class
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>));

            // Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
            TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");
            SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, lstNewItems);

            // Cleanup
            WriteFileStream.Close();

            #endregion

            // Load items to control
            #region Load the object

            // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
            FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

            // Load the object saved above by using the Deserialize function
            List<Item> LoadedObj = (List<Item>)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);

            // Cleanup
            ReadFileStream.Close();

            #endregion

            // Load up all the settings

            for (int i = 0; i < LoadedObj.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
            {
                String ThisisAnItemToControl = LoadedObj[i].Paramater;
                String ThisIsItsType = LoadedObj[i].Type;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

[ProtoBuf Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) is a binary serializer but it is very flexible and fast

Answer (score 1):

for structured data,  either XML or a very lightweight SQL RDBMS like SQLite or SQL Server Compact Edition will work well

I recommend `XML` reader/writer class for files because it is easily serialized
Serialization  is an easy way to convert an object to a binary representation that can then be  written to disk or sent over a wire.